# Как отобразить дерево в Github Desktop?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

Только начал знакомиться с git.

Как отобразить дерево с указанием коммитов и разветвлений, как на картинке, в Github Desktop?

[image: Дерево git]

Comment: `gitk` запускали?

Comment: Что такое gitk ?